# What's the best way to hide the index in a Panda DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/YouToozBot/info.csv")
df.reset_index()


url = df.loc[:"url"]
print(f'The bots URL is set to {url}')
```

When I execute it, I get the information from the csv file, but I have "0      " in front of it (the index). How should I go about getting rid of the index? I've looked around but nothing has worked.

Comment: You should show the first lines of the csv file, and make sure that the interesting line is there (add it if it is not). Then tell us what is the info that you want. It will help to write relevant answers.

Comment: What did you try so far?